# How can I include library functions from assembly files in my compiler using llvmpy?

Tags: compiler-construction, llvm, llvm-py

I have to include some functions, that I have implemented in 8086 assembly, in my compilers project for a C-like programming language. That is, I have 6 .asm files. I have used so far llvmpy (a no longer maintained python tool, but still more complete than llvm lite). How can I include these library functions?

Comment: Take a look into inline assembly: https://github.com/llvmpy/llvmpy/blob/master/test/inlineasm.py

Comment: You can link the .o files of your .asm files with the .o file of your compiler using `lld`